# apache 2.2 order deny allow not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, access-control-list

this is driving me nuts. In a web server running httpd-2.2.15-45.el6.centos.x86_64 any type of  does not seem to be honored.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.10:80>
    ServerName mas.domain.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/sites/mas.domain.com/cgi-bin/"
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/mas.domain.com
    <Directory /home/sites/mas.domain.com/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from  all
    </Directory>
```

This is supposed to deny anything. But it appears that it does not work at all. 
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the exhaustive [on-line documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order).

The `Deny,Allow` order actually defaults to `Allow`.

```
|Match                  |Allow,Deny result  |Deny,Allow result |
|-----------------------|-------------------|------------------|
|Match Allow only       |Request allowed    |Request allowed   |
|Match Deny only        |Request denied     |Request denied    |
|No match               |Default to Denied  |Default to Allowed|
|Match both Allow & Deny|Denied             |Allowed           |
```

Comment: Still the same problem:

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from  all